# When is a critical section for database insertion?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

Here is my code inserting into the database using sequelize.

```
insertUser: function() { 
    User.build({
        firstName: 'John'
    }).save().then(newUser => {
        const race = Race.build({
            name: 'Spa'
        });
        race.setUser(newUser);
        race.save();
    });
}
```

I'm still not familiar with asynchronous/synchronous javascript critical sections. Here I use a Promise after the insertion of a User, so I'm able to get his id, and so be able to create a race with his attribute. Afterwards I'm building and setting up the foreign key from race before saving it.

My question is: should I put a new Promise before race.save(), to wait for the foreign key attribute to be set up before saving it, and avoid to save a possible race without foreign key? Or is here everything from the .then( on, gonna run continuously? And Why?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us use your code to clear things up:

```
User.build({
    firstName: 'John'
}).save().then(newUser => {
    const race = Race.build({
        name: 'Spa'
    });
    console.log("2");
    race.setUser(newUser);
    console.log("3")
    race.save().then(race => {
        console.log("5");
    });
    console.log("4");
});
console.log("1")
```

Whenever you perform an async action like going to the database, instead of waiting for the operation to finish (block), node continues in order not to waste cycles that could be used to execute something else. In the example above we have several save() calls. Before we get to the second console.log, we have a save, meaning that node will continue and will log the first message at the very bottom. Upon the completion of the save() call it continues in the then() block. Since setUser is not async, it will set the user and then print 3. When we call save again, we are going to the database again and will print 4 before continuing and printing 5.

Comment: "Since setUser is not async", how do we know that?  I didn't create the methode setUser, it is a method generated by sequelize.js. The only way to be certain it's not async, it's to watch the documentation of this method?

Comment: You have to look at the documentation/implementation of the method. Usually an async method will have a callback parameter or it will return a promise.

Comment: Ok thank you! I was too concerned about the "javascript is asynchronous".

Answer (score 1):

You are already waiting for the Promise from the `User.build.save()` to resolve (the first argument to `then()` is the promise success callback) before creating the Race. What would you actually yield a promise from before saving the race that is created with the resolved-return value from User.build?

Semantically your program flow is:

1. create a User with firstName attribute 'John'
2. wait for this user to be to committed.
3. When it's saved successfully, you get back a the user object you just saved, assign it to the variable `newUser` and build a new Race object called `race` with the name attribute 'Spa'
4. set the user of `race` to `newUser`
5. commit `race`.

If the user of `race` is a foreign key to User, then you already guarantee the order of operations with what you currently have, since the creation of the Race inside the first argument of `then()` means you are waiting for the user to be committed before creating Race.

Compare this to:

```
function() {
    const newUser = User.build({
        firstName: 'John'}).save();

    const race = Race.build({
        name: 'Spa'
    });

    race.setUser(newUser);

    // newUser might not exist before attaching it to race!

    race.save();

    // if Race requires user as a foreign key, Integrity error
    // can be thrown if newUser didn't exist yet
}
```

Comment: My confusion is, is race.setUser(newUser) and race.save() going to work in synchronus way. Or could race.save() start before race.setUser(newUser)?

Comment: to be totally sure, how is `setUser` defined? If it doesn't return a promise or take a callback by itself it is probably a "synchronous" setter function. If you aren't calling nextTick or setTimeout in `setUser` or triggering/invoking an event it is synchronous.

Comment: I think my confusion came from the idea that everything in javascript is asynchronous, but as I see now, everything is synchronous except certain functions we wish to be asynchrous?

Comment: asynchronous code relies on an event loop. asynchronous methods are defined to tell the event loop to save its state when the method is called, then move on. When the async method returns, the current loop is interrupted and the method's callback function is called with the return value. Promises are a type of standard interface your async method can implement to facilitate interacting with its state along any subsequent part of the event loop.